# Does universal construction apply to any arbitrary category?

Tags: category-theory, universal-property

Does universal construction presuppose a category equipped with morphisms that implement an order?

Otherwise how does the universal construction pick the most suitable element for the given purpose?

How does "more suitable" or "best" is defined for an arbitrary category?

Comment: What kind of universal property do you have in mind? What kind of categories have you seen them in? Are you comfortable with how the universal property for a direct product works in various categories?

Comment: I've encountered universal construction in the context of the categorical product so far. I think the underlying category was a thin category but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 2):

There's nothing like "best" or "most suitable" around a universal property, it's always **uniqueness** of certain arrows/diagrams, even in a non-thin category.

Moreover, *everything* with universal property is simply an *initial object* 'somewhere', i.e. in a suitable category $\mathcal B$, it is an object $O$ such that for every object $B$ there is one and only one morphism $O\to B$.

For instance, its dual, a terminal object of a category $\mathcal A$ is an initial object of the opposite category $\mathcal A^{op}$. 
The coproduct of objects $A_i$ is an initialal object in the category of 'cocones over $A_i$'s'
[ which has the cocones $(\underset{A_i\to X}{f_i})_i$ as objects and those  $u:X\to Y$ morphisms as morphisms $(f_i)_i\to (g_i)_i$ which satisfy $u\circ f_i = g_i$ for each $i$.] 
Similarly, any colimit can be seen as an initial object of the category of cocones over the given diagram. 
Dually, any limit is a terminal object of the category of cones over the given diagram, so that it's an initial object of its opposite category.